# Tensorflow: how to use an estimator trained earlier

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I'm looking at the official tensorflow tutorial here:https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

Basically, it teaches you how to train a classifier for the mnist dataset.

The complete code is pretty short and can be found here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py

I can run it without any problems. But I want to know how I can reuse the estimator trained in this file for some other program. The model is saved as 3 files: one .data-00000-of-00001 file, one .meta file and one .index file.

I googled and it seems you can load the model by:

```
sess=tf.Session()    
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_model.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

But how do I proceed from here? It seems weird the tutorial does not teach you how to reuse the estimator.

Answer (score 0):

Importing meta graph does not explicitly load your nodes in meta-graph.
It only loads the nodes 'internally'. and this internal nodes have names you assigned before like

```
tf.truncated_normal([28, 128], stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(28))), name="weights1")
```

In this case "weights1" is your 'internal' node name.
Then you should draw out(assign) your 'internal' node to 'external' variable (code level).

```
# bring out a "weights1" node from meta graph
fc_weights1 = tf.get_collection('weights1')
```

And like this way, you can do

```
logits = tf.get_collection('logits_node_before_you_named')
```

and you can write new loss, accuracy node you've done before.
In summary, you can pull out nodes you want to use to the surface(code level) by using  `tf.get_collection` method.

P.S. Use of these 'internal', 'external' terms is not official, and is for convenience only.